# YouTube animatic about a girl who lives in a forest and can turn people to stone

Tags: story-identification, anime, animation

I think it was a YouTube animatic. All I remember is the style was anime looking and it was in Japanese.
A girl with black hair (I’m not sure if it was short or long) was looking out a window with vines and stuff on it. People came hunting and looking for her in a forest where she lives. She can turn people into stone, I think, and she has red eyes.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it might be a scene from either *Kagerou Project*, a series of anime music videos that form a shared narrative, or *Mekakucity Actors*, an anime that adapts the story of *Kagerou Project*.

One of the main characters, Marry Kozakura, has the ability to turn people into stone. Her mother, Azami, has black hair and has the same ability. Their eyes aren't normally red, but they turn red whenever they use this ability. I'm not sure about *Kagerou Project*, but in *Mekakucity Actors*, their backstory is mostly told through post-credits scenes animated in the style of a storybook, resembling an animatic:

I believe the scene in question, with the ivy-covered house in the forest, is when a lynch mob comes to attack Azami and Marry: